# Why is the xlsx file transmitted by WeChat file in HTML format?

Tags: php, file, phpexcel, xlsx, wechat

Recently using PHPEXCEL to handle xlsx files, when the file is downloaded through WeChat, it is always identified by PHPEXCEL as a HTML file, but it is really a xlsx suffix and can also be opened with WPS. if I use linux command such as "file fileName.xlsx", then I got the result:

`HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines`

Is this the result of WeChat transmission?

Comment: XLSX files are essentially just giant XML files, what do you see when you open the file in a text editor like vim/nano?

Comment: I open the file with vim,and I see it begin with <html ...>,obviously that's a html file,does it cause by WeChat transmission?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't get the file, and the download's header redirected to something other than the file. Rename it to end in .htm, open it in a browser and see what it is.